# Whether this function is correct or not?

Tags: javascript

alert(window.location.href/&name=" + escape(name_var) + "&id=" + escape(id_var));

thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not correct.

```
alert(window.location.href + "&name=" + encodeURIComponent(name_var) + "&id=" + encodeURIComponent(id_var));
```

1. You have a syntax error in your code, the `/` that follows `window.location.href`
2. Use the concatenation operator, `+` - `myString + "more string"`
3. `escape` is deprecated, use `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: @bobince: dammit, I keep confusing them!